# How to scale up parent div and show hidden child div on hover without affecting surrounding divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm working on company service boxes and need the following...

```
On hover:
1. Parent div scales up and gets box shadow without affecting the other service boxes around it (it should sort of pop up over top of the other service boxes)
2. A hidden child div comes into view as the parent is scaling up
3. The other service boxes shouldn't move or be affected
On hover out:
Reverse happens
```

I have it to where it scales up on hover, and shows the hidden child div with text... but it's moving the other service boxes around it. Any help?

Here is a sample of where I'm at so far... https://codepen.io/Finches/pen/jayePK

Thanks!

Comment: You are displaying another div which will take space so other will move

Answer (score 0):

You could add this to the visible class in your css:

```
position : fixed;
bottom : -20px;
left : 0;
```

You need to test it further.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `display` property, use the `visibility` property. This will keep the excerpts invisible but the flow of your document won't be updated upon showing the items.

```
.service-excerpt {
    visibility: hidden;
    color: #005CAB;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.visible {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```js
$('.service-box').hover(function(){
    $(this).children('.service-excerpt').addClass('visible');
}, function(){
    $(this).children('.service-excerpt').removeClass('visible');
})
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.service-link {
  width: 50%;
}

.service-box {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin:0;
    padding:25px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) { 
    .service-box {
        width: 25%;
    }
  
  .service-link {
    width: 25%;
  }
}

.service-icon {
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.service-icon img {
  width: 100%;
}

.service-title {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
    color: #37CC96;
}

.service-excerpt {
    visibility: hidden;
    color: #005CAB;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.service-box:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #ddd;
}

.visible {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="service-container">
  <a class="service-link" href="#">
    <div class="service-box">
      <div class="service-icon">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" />
      </div>
      <div class="service-title">Service Title</div>
      <div class="service-excerpt">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at.</div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="service-link" href="#">
    <div class="service-box">
      <div class="service-icon">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" />
      </div>
      <div class="service-title">Service Title</div>
      <div class="service-excerpt">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College.</div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="service-link" href="#">
    <div class="service-box">
      <div class="service-icon">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" />
      </div>
      <div class="service-title">Service Title</div>
      <div class="service-excerpt">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.</div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="service-link" href="#">
    <div class="service-box">
      <div class="service-icon">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" />
      </div>
      <div class="service-title">Service Title</div>
      <div class="service-excerpt">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor.</div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="service-link" href="#">
    <div class="service-box">
      <div class="service-icon">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" />
      </div>
      <div class="service-title">Service Title</div>
      <div class="service-excerpt">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor.</div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="service-link" href="#">
    <div class="service-box">
      <div class="service-icon">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" />
      </div>
      <div class="service-title">Service Title</div>
      <div class="service-excerpt">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock.</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help... This is close, but if the excerpts that fade in are different lengths for each service box, it throws their positioning out of whack. It's preferable to not display the excerpts until the box is hovered, then have the box expand to show it while not affecting the surrounding service boxes.